# Be important to do/doing

Tags: verb-forms

> Recycling is important to help protect our planet’s natural resources and to **help** fight climate change.

https://www.wychavon.gov.uk/waste-and-recycling/recycling

Is that the correct form of the verb？  I think -ing form is needed，as in:

> The agreement is essential to *spurring* economic growth around the world.( Oxford dictionary)

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Oxford dictionary example suggests, it would certainly be possible to write:

> Recycling is important to helping fight climate change.

However, your sentence provides two reasons for which recycling is important:

1. to help protect our planet’s natural resources
2. to help fight climate change

Notice that these reasons are contained in a series, as they are connected by the coordinating conjunction "and". They are also in the same form (each headed by a full infinitive), thus satisfying [the principle of parallelism](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/en/writing-tips-plus/faulty-parallelism). Therefore, the sentence is correct as written, and you should only change the form of the second full infinitive<sup>1</sup> if you also changed the form of the first to maintain the parallelism:

> Recycling is important to helping protect our planet’s natural resources and to helping fight climate change.

---

<sup>1</sup>You only bolded the second "help", so I assume that your question is only about changing that word.

Comment: Okay, I get it.  Both forms are  grammatical in that construction and readily interchangeable.  But the principle of parallelism requires  verbs in the coordinate construction are in the same form.

Comment: @Robbyzhu Yes, exactly. (By the way, if you use "helping", I think that "important for" would work better than "important to".)